# How do I install Cheese 3.0?

Tags: 11.04, installation, webcam, cheese

After seeing an article on Cheese 3.0 and it's new effects some months back, it was going to be one of the major highlights of 11.04 to me.

Sadly, I find 3.0 is not in the repo; it has been released, just not soon enough before the freeze.

So how do I install Cheese 3.0 in Ubuntu 11.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need GNOME 3 to run Cheese 3.0 while Ubuntu 11.04 has GNOME 2.32. So, what to do?

Wait a few weeks until the GNOME3 PPA has been throughly tested and install GNOME3 alongside to Unity. Then, you can install Cheese 3.0.
Instructions at https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3

**NOTE**: Do not install the PPA yet. Currently the PPA is experimental, and there is no going back (removing GNOME3 to go back to Unity).

Comment: So, no cheese 3.0 for Unity then? :(

Comment: So, what, they have GNOME Shell integrated into GNOME 3 libraries? Or are the *GNOME 3 libraries* (and not Shell) the things that would break Unity?

Answer (score 0):

You can download Cheese 3.0.1 from:

- ftp://ftp.gnome.org/mirror/gnome.org/apps/3.0/3.0.1/sources/cheese-3.0.1.tar.gz

Extract the file, click on the extracted file named **cheese-3.0.1** then click on the file named **INSTALL** which tells you how to go about installing Cheese 3.0.1